# Site Has Disappeared, "Server Error" in MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I have not accessed my site I have been building with `MAMP` and `Wordpress` for a few days and I tried to log on today. When I tried to start the servers in MAMP, I recived an error message saying something like,

> 'Error. Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP
>   installation.'

So I decided to copy some of what I thought was vital to my site within the `htdocs` folder in MAMP and then deleted and uninstalled MAMP. I then reinstalled MAMP, placed my folder in htdocs and started the servers. they started however I am getting the message,

> 'Server error'

with an error code of `500` below it. I am quite confused and sorry if this is all too simple for your time but any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will need the DB that went along with WP.

Comment: you should configure database connectivity check **wp-config.php**

Comment: I recommend checking the permissions on the folder placed in htdocs